# Using office 365 API without Aceess directory

Tags: office365

I am interested in integrating office365 with my application. Is it possible to add a user to an office 365 account via the office365 API without the use of an active directory? I just want to call an API method which will create the user on office 365 account without adding that same user to office 365.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Active directory is the authentication method for o365 application integration.   No way around it really.

Its really not that bad.  Integrate your o365 with Azure AD, add your app to your AD, get  a token and go.  The labs in this free Microsoft Virtual Academy class do a great job walking you through it.  Pay attention to Lab#5, introduction to the o365 dev apis.

http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/introduction-to-office-365-development

Comment: good dialog on this here - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0c9a66de-39c7-4a21-876d-0bf79528b42a/office-365-without-azure-active-directory?forum=WindowsAzureAD

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
This office 365 document (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn197201.aspx) also says so. Just wanted to see if there is an alternative way.

Comment: NP.  I'm hanging w some O365 super-gurus at BUILD and Ignite.  I'm going to push this to them and see if they might have any ideas.